# Completely Factory Reset my computer help!

Tags: tag

I am not happy with the results of an overwrite of windows 7 with Linux. My laptop never came with a Windows 7 installation disc, yet I'd love to go back to Windows 7. How would I go about doing this? If you need any computer info, tell me.

Comment: Did you "overwrite" Windows? If so, then you must get a Windows installation DVD to install it. If you are dual-booting add that information to question, please.

Answer (score 2):

If you did indeed overwrite it, then you will need to get a hold of a windows install disc, or use an .iso to make a usb install drive.

Microsoft actually provides a tool for this. http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool

Comment: so basically your saying i'm screwed unless i get a windows install disc?